# The Pkg REPL-mode [opts]?

Tags: julia, documentation, pkg-config

Where the list of command options and their documentation for Package Mode or Package Management could be found?
cmd [opts] [args]
For example:
st -m Plots GR
where I could read about the option: -m
And the possible options for each command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interactively, you can use the `help` command in the package REPL mode:

```
julia> # type ] to enter package mode
(@v1.5) pkg> help st
  [st|status] [-d|--diff] [pkgs...]
  [st|status] [-d|--diff] [-p|--project] [pkgs...]
  [st|status] [-d|--diff] [-m|--manifest] [pkgs...]

  Show the status of the current environment. In --project mode (default),
  the status of the project file is summarized. In --manifest mode the
  output also includes the recursive dependencies of added packages given
  in the manifest. If there are any packages listed as arguments the
  output will be limited to those packages. The --diff option will, if the
  environment is in a git repository, limit the output to the difference
  as compared to the last git commit.

  │ Julia 1.1
  │
  │  pkg> status with package arguments requires at least Julia 1.1.

  │ Julia 1.3
  │
  │  The --diff option requires Julia 1.3. In earlier versions --diff is
  |  the default for environments in git repositories.
```

Apart from that, all commands of Pkg's REPL mode (including `status` or `help`) are described in [`Pkg.jl`'s documentation](https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/v1.5/repl/)